# Find trends in search engines query log

Tags: algorithm, data-mining

I am trying to do some research with search queries logs. My first interest is to found trends. 
For example: at winter people often have a cold sore. So i guess that at winter we can see growth of such type queries.

How i want to detect trends:

1. Using apriory algorithm or something to get a frequent item set.
2. Count number of each set in a time range (one hour, one day etc)
3. Use linear regression to found relative function change
   if this is a regression ax + b, then we just calculate (a*(first_date)+b)/(a*(second_date)+b)

So  i have a problem:
It's very hard to found frequent item set on large set of data (i have millions queries). I had implemented apriory algorithm but it's working very slow with low support ( for example 2 on 200k queries might take a day)

What is best algorithm in my case? Maybe i can solve my task in another way?

Comment: @Yavar I have only one machine(or two). So that's why i cannt go distributed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thaught that will narrow it down to counting only the strings in the requested time frame, and not the entire collection.

 Store your queries in a sorted expandable data structure - I think a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) will be a good fit here.

The order of the queries in the skip list will be by time, ascending. 

Note: adding a new query to the skip list is easy - you always append it, because it is always "bigger" then (happened after)  all existing queries.

Now, when you need to search for a time frame - you do not need to iterate over all queries, but rather on the relevant part of it alone, since finding the first and last elements of the time frame can be done fast in a skip list.

To improve efficiency, I'd use a bi-map to give unique ID to each string, and store only the IDs. creating a histogram out of the IDs is likely to be easier (computationally speaking) then creating it for the original strings. After you have found the most frequent IDs - you can deduce which strings they refer to from the map.